# MVC, Repository Pattern and DataLoadOptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

I have a little project where I'm running MVC3. 
I use LINQ to fetch data from the database.
I built my project with the same architectural design as the premade examples that come with MVC3.
In such a project, the application is split up and in this topic I want to focus on the Model.cs files. I have one for each controller at the moment, So as an example, I have a HighscoreController.cs and a HighscoreModels.cs. In the model class I define a Service class that has a reference to a datacontext and some methods that use this datacontext to query the database.
Now i ran into the problem that some of these methods are executing the same queries, and therefore I wanted to make a central point of access to the database so I thought I would implement the Repository Pattern, and so I did. 
So instead of having a reference to a datacontext in the Service class I now have a reference to the repository as such:

```
    private IRepository _repository;

    public HighscoreService()
        : this(new Repository())
    { }

    public HighscoreService(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

Now the database calls are handled within the repository and the repository is used from the Service class through the _repository reference.

My repository is built like this:

```
   public class Repository : IRepository
   {
    private MyDataContext _dataContext;

    public Repository()
    {
        _dataContext = new MyDataContext();
    }

    public Member MemberByName(string memberName)
    {
        Member member = CompiledQueries.MemberByName(_dataContext, memberName);
        return member;
    }
    }
```

The problem I face appears when I try to use DataLoadOptions in combination with this repository pattern.

Because when you use dataloadoptions, you must not have made previous queries on the datacontext before a new dataloadoptions is applied to it. And since my repository reuses the datacontext throughout all methods, this does not work out at all. 
I have been trying 2 things, one is recreating the datacontext within every methods, by way of the using statement, to make sure that the datacontext is refreshed every time. But then I get problems when I have fetched the result from the repository back into my model and the scope runs out inside the repository pattern, as the using statement ends, which means that the result cannot be used with e.g. .Count() or .ToList() because the datacontext that supplied me the data has been terminated. I also tried another solution where it uses the same datacontext throughout the whole repository, but makes a new instance in each method that uses dataloadoptions. This felt very dirty ;)
So can anyone give me a suggestion on how to use DataLoadOptions with the repository pattern? and avoid the problems I just described. Or should i not use dataloadoptions and choose another way of doing it? The reason i use DataLoadOptions by the way, is that I want to have some data from related tables.

As a little question on the side: In the code example above you can see that I have placed CompiledQueries within a .cs file of its own. Is this a bad design? Are there any guidelines for where to put compiled queries in an MVC application?

Thanks for reading and hope there are some answers for my questions ;) thanks a lot in advance. If you need more information, just ask.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think the idea of keeping your data context in "request scope" may help.  This way a new context would be created per HTTP request, which may remove some of your problems.  An IoC container such as Ninject can help with this.  While it's in reference to Entity Framework, the following post might help: http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/24/dependency-injection-with-ninject-moq-and-unit-testing/

Comment: Inject your repository and setup the lifestyle as perWebRequest. Not sure at this point what the repository is doing for you except for adding a useless layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am by no means an expert on `DataLoadOptions`, but from your question and what I've read about it, it seems that you need to use it for eager loading. In reference to this:

"Because when you use dataloadoptions, you must not have made previous queries on the datacontext before a new dataloadoptions is applied to it."

.. to me this sounds like a shortcoming or design flaw with `DataLoadOptions` (I personally use Entity Framework, not LINQ to SQL). While I do think it's a good idea to have a single data context per HTTP request as offered in the first 2 comments by ngm and CrazyCoderz, I don't think this will solve your problem. If you want to reuse a single data context within a single HTTP request, as soon as you execute the first query, it sounds like you will be unable to set the `DataLoadOptions` on the data context to a new value.

I saw a presentation at vslive vegas where the presenter offered one of the solutions you mentioned, creating a new data context in each repository method. What you would have to do here is call ToList() or ToArray() **before** terminating the using statement and returning the method result(s).

As you mentioned, this would make objects not pre-loaded into the enumeration inaccessible after the method returns. However, if you already have the query executed and converted to a `List`, `Collection`, `Array`, or some other concrete `IEnumerable`, you don't need access to the `Count()` or `ToList()` **methods** any longer. Instead, you can use `Array.Length` or `List.Count` or `Collection.Count` **properties**.

What else is stopping you from creating a new data context in each repository method? Meaning, what do you need the data context for, after executing the repository method, that you can't get because it's been disposed of?

**Reply to comments**

For your first query, can you do this?

```
public Member GetSomeRandomMember()
{
    Member[] members = null;
    using (var context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        // execute the query to get the whole table
        members = context.Members.ToArray();
    }

    // do not need to query again
    var totalRows = members.Length;
    var skipThisMany = PerformRandomNumberComputation(totalRows);
    return members.Skip(skipThisMany).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Granted that might not be optimal if your Members table has a lot of rows. In that case you would want to execute 2 queries -- 1 to count, and a second to select the row. You could achieve that by opening 2 contexts:

```
public Member GetSomeRandomMember()
{
    using (var context1 = new MyDataContext())
        var totalRows = context1.Members.Count();

    var skipThisMany = PerformRandomNumberComputation(totalRows);

    Member member = null;
    using (var context2 = new MyDataContext())
        member = context2.Members.Skip(skipThisMany).FirstOrDefault();

    return member;
}
```

For the second part of your comment, I'm not sure I get what you are talking about. The fetching of the data and the making changes to it should all come in a single operation with a single context anyways:

```
public void SaveMember(int id, string email, bool isSuspended)
{
    using (var context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        var member = context.Members.Single(m => m.Id == id);
        member.Email = email;
        member.IsSuspended = isSuspended;
        context.SaveChanges(); // or whatever the linq to sql equivalent is
    }
}
```

If you want to pass the whole entity to the repository method, you should still query it out so that it is attached to the correct context:

```
public void SaveMember(Member member)
{
    var memberDto = member;
    using (var context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        member = context.Members.Single(m => m.Id == memberDto.Id);
        member.Email = memberDto.Email;
        member.IsSuspended = memberDto.IsSuspended;
        context.SaveChanges(); // or whatever the linq to sql equivalent is
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now I'm loading a whole table, I then perform a count on it, and based on the count I generate a random number, which is then used in a .Skip(randomNumber).FirstOrDefault() on the same loaded results. So if I can't lazily load it, then I'd have to split it up into 2 queries, one for getting the count, and one to get my actual row. Another problem I have with terminating the context is fetching data and making changes to it, and putting it back, since, when the context is terminated, it cannot properly insert changes to a loaded result that you had previously gotten.

Comment: Thanks again for your answers and brilliant code examples. I'm not sure what I think of the first part, opening many datacontexts, since I dont know how performance heavy it is to do so. I guess I was hoping for some magical solution that was a bit cleaner ;) The second part makes a lot of sense, and I shall make sure I do it like that instead. Thanks

Comment: @emin, while I don't think it's ideal to open & dispose of 2 data contexts, this is a case where you might have to weigh performance of one option versus the other. By doing the first code snippet, you are in essence executing `SELECT * FROM Members` on the db. This will cause the db to return all rows into memory. If your Members table has thousands or millions of rows, this will be slow and expensive. The second option instead does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Members`, then `SELECT * FROM Members WHERE ID = @ID`, and will always be more performant when you have a lot of rows in the table.